# OpenIdConnect: how to add additional claims in the token?

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm quite new to OpenIdConnect so excuse me if i still miss some basic concept.
I have a SPA-style web application I'm developing for my company (AspNet Core + Aurelia).
I want to use AzureAD via OpenIdConnect for authentication and authorization, everything works very well so far i'm able to obrain a token and sign in.

the problem is that my application needs to provide to the client's browser some app-specific claims like: can read X, can edit Y...

- if i add these claims to the JWT token provided by AzureAD obviously it will became invalid, as the signature will not match the content.
- if i generate a new token with the new claims, but signed with the app key, obviously it will be a different token valid only in the context of my app (what if I'll later need to access some other resource using the AzureAD token?, is it a good idea to insert the AzureID token as claim of the newly issued token?)

Are there something I'm missing in the OpenConnectId? or is there a way to *add* claims to a token issued by a 3rd-party provider like AzureAD while keeping the token valid? Maybe a way to ask AzureAd to add claims to the token and re-sign it?

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to solve this situation may be to obtain an access_token for my own application's api (from my app backend) in exchange of the id_token provided by azure (after its validation)

so the application frontend in the browser will own two tokens and it will be able to use the correct one for each type of request.

there are some standardized flow that are quite similar to this but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a custom claim mapping policy. This is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#claims-mapping-policy-assignment).

> This feature is used by tenant admins to customize the claims emitted in tokens for a specific application in their tenant.

As far as I can understand, this is still in preview stage. So it may require some trial and error verification.

Alternatively, you can define some policy in your application itself. Given that you know client IDs from your application (hence you require to use them for OpenID Connect requests), you may create a simple policy to check tokens and perform verifications.